# OpenCart Manufactures DropDown

Tags: php, html, opencart

I'm trying to add manufacturers to the dropdown menu dynamically, I wrote a foreach statement but nothing is showing up on the front page.

Can anyone check the code and shed some light, would appreciate the help.

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu-holder" class="<?php echo (isset($styler['menu_style']) && ($styler['menu_style']!='')) ? $styler['menu_style']."_menu" : '' ;?>">
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><span class='home_icon'></span></a>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><?php if ($category['children']) { ?><span></span><?php } ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a<?php echo ($i==(count($category['children'])-1) ? " class='last_submenu_item'" : '');?> href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></span></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Football Clubs</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please give example of your output HTML

Comment: Here is the output from the code above, there should be a extra link where the arrow is pointing to: http://i59.tinypic.com/90ynmc.png

Comment: Let me know if you guys need anything else to help me on this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow below 4 steps & add below 4 steps code in your site & then check it.**

## Step 1

Replace below code instead of your code.

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu-holder" class="<?php echo (isset($styler['menu_style']) && ($styler['menu_style']!='')) ? $styler['menu_style']."_menu" : '' ;?>">
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><span class='home_icon'></span></a></li>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><?php if ($category['children']) { ?><span></span><?php } ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a<?php echo ($i==(count($category['children'])-1) ? " class='last_submenu_item'" : '');?> href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></span></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a>
      <div>
      <ul>
      <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Football Clubs</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

---

## Step 2

Go to your source > catalog > controller > common > & then Open **"header.php"** file.

**Find:**

```
$this->data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');
```

**Add After:**

```
$this->data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
```

---

## Step 3

Go to your source > catalog > controller > common > & then Open **"header.php"** file.

**Find:**

```
$this->data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
```

**Add After:**

```
$this->data['manufacturer'] = $this->url->link('product/manufacturer');
```

---

## Step 4

Go to your source > catalog > controller > common > & then Open **"header.php"** file.

**Find:**

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

**Add After:**

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
    $this->load->model('tool/image');
    $results = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();
    foreach ($results as $result) { 
        $this->data['manufacturers'][] = array(
            'name' => $result['name'],
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
        );
    }
```

& then check it.

Comment: Worked perfectly, so what i was missing is the language and the module in the controller section...

Answer (score 0):

Try print_r your array just making sure you are pointing things to the right places.

Some code I noticed, that you might want to look at.

```
if ($category['children']) { ?><span></span><?php }
```

Home li has no closing tag

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><span class='home_icon'></span></a></li>
```

Semicolon within count()

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) {
```

should have everything constructed in php as a string then output and use of foreach to loop instead would prevent less errors